# How can I make a form field read-only after a certain date?

Tags: php, forms, field

example I have a dollar amount and I dont want the franchise to edit the field after the 10th of previous month

Comment: The current date is *always* "after the 10th of [the] previous month".

Answer (score 0):

Get a fixed date time and get a system time same format. Then difference the time like

```
$diff_time = $systime- $fixed_time;
```

extract month of $diff_time

```
if($diff_time_mon>10){
your form with "readonly"
}
else{
your form without "readonly"
}
```